# In prestashop how to write code for disable a module function only for specified categories

Tags: prestashop

I need to disable a module only for a particular category.How do i need to write code for making the module to diable for those categories.

Answer (score 0):

like this (if you want to disable your module for id category 4) :

```
$id_category = (int)Tools::getValue('id_category');
if($id_category !==4){
//some code
}
```

Comment: what is the code i need to write for disable the cash on delivery module @prestarocket